# What is "\00" in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, null, escaping

What does "\00" mean in Python? To learn more about this, I tried following:

- When I assign `d="\00"` and call `print d`, nothing displays on the screen.
- I also tried assigning `d` to a string with extra spacing between and at the end and then called `d.replace("\00", "")`, but no result was evident.

What does `d.replace("\00","")` do? Will it merely look for this particular string **"\00"** and replace it with an empty string?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Python 2, when a number starts with a leading zero, it means it's in octal (base 8). In Python 3 octal literals start with `0o` instead. `00` specifically is 0.

The leading `\` in `\00` is a way of specifying a byte value, a number between 0-255. It's normally used to represent a character that isn't on your keyboard, or otherwise can't be easily represented in a string. Some special characters also have non-numeric "escape codes", like `\n` for a newline.

The zero byte is also known as the nul byte or null byte. It doesn't display anything when printed -- it's null.

See http://www.ascii.cl/ for ASCII character codes.

Yes, `replace` will still work with it, it just has no meaning as a display character.

It's sometimes used for other purposes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character.

Comment: So what will `replace` do ?. Will it merely treat "\00" as a plain string; to be replace by "".

Comment: Yes, it will replace the zero byte with whatever string you specify, just as if you replaced 'a' or ' ' (space) or '\t' (tab).

Comment: @agf note that '\0' is actually base 8 not base 10. It doesn't make any difference for nulls, but as soon as you start using it for any character over 7 it will make a big difference.

Comment: @Duncan is right -- `\0` is octal, while `\x00` is hexadecimal, and both are null.

Answer (score 12):

The backslash followed by a number is used to represent the character with that octal value. So your  `\00` represents [ASCII NUL](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html).

Comment: No such thing as "ASCII NULL". It's `NUL`. `NULL` is the SQL equivalent of Python's `None`.

Comment: @JohnMachin, or [NULL is to NUL](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html) what LINE FEED is to LF (meaning vs abbreviation)